# Add custom title to a data-frame in Pandas and convert it to HTML

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, csv, data-science

I am reading certain csv files from list of directories namely actual_results and expected_results. Now I glob through each csv in actual_results and compare it csvs in expected_results. Then I want to display the whole data into an HTML as below

I have already written some code for actually cleaning the data and then comparing the data-frames for actual and expected csvs.

Here is the whole code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
from glob import glob
import os
import itertools

# compareCSV takes in two args as path of the two csv files to compare
def compare(expectedList,actualList):
    ctr=0
    dfList = list()
    for (csv1,csv2) in itertools.zip_longest(expectedList,actualList):
        df1_ctr=pd.read_csv(csv1,sep=',')
        df1_ctr[df1_ctr.columns[1:]] = [x.split('\t') for x in df1_ctr['mean(ms)']]
        df1=df1_ctr.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
        df2_ctr=pd.read_csv(csv2,sep=',')
        df2_ctr[df2_ctr.columns[1:]] = [x.split('\t') for x in df2_ctr['mean(ms)']]
        df2=df2_ctr.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
        print("Dataframe for Expected List for file : {} is \n {}".format(csv1,df1))
        print("Dataframe for Actual List for file: {} is \n {}".format(csv2,df2))
        d3=df1.loc[:,:] # Dataframe 1
        d4=df2.loc[:,:] # Dataframe 2
        d5=abs(((d3.subtract(d4))/d3)*100)
        print("Deviation between file {} and {} is :\n {}".format(csv1,csv2,d5))
        ctr=ctr+1  
        #Final Data frame
        df=pd.concat([df1,df2,d5])
        #print("{}".format(df))
        dfList.append(df)   
    #print("Final Data frame: \n{}".format(dfList))
    # for data in dfList:
    #     print("data at index: \n{}".format(data))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #file1=sys.argv[1]  # FileName1
    #file2=sys.argv[2]  #FileName2
    #compareCSV(file1,file2) # Compare CSV files passed in as paramters
    os.chdir("expected_results")
    expectedCSVs=glob("*.csv")
    #print(expectedCSVs)
    os.chdir("../actual_results")
    actualCSVs=glob("*.csv")
    #print(actualCSVs)
    compare(expectedCSVs,actualCSVs)
```

I have some redundant print statements at the moment.
Output of the above code is below:

```
Dataframe for Expected List for file : CT_QRW_25.csv is 
    100%Q   mean(ms)   P50(ms)     P99(ms)   p99.9(ms)  #Samples
0    NaN   0.038973  0.044939    0.091076    0.363859   1760108
1    NaN   0.050652  0.044963    0.094738    0.402525   1354233
2    NaN   0.046500  0.045020    0.108138    0.320636    123448
3    NaN   1.872630  0.599966   33.313200  172.040000  21954617
4    NaN  37.752900  0.600484  603.063000  805.340000   2708258
Dataframe for Actual List for file: CT_QRW_25.csv is 
    100%Q   mean(ms)   P50(ms)     P99(ms)   p99.9(ms)  #Samples
0    NaN   0.038973  0.044939    0.091076    0.363859   1760108
1    NaN   0.050652  0.044963    0.094738    0.402525   1354233
2    NaN   0.046500  0.045020    0.108138    0.320636    123448
3    NaN   1.872630  0.599966   33.313200  172.040000  21954617
4    NaN  37.752900  0.600484  603.063000  805.340000   2708258
Deviation between file CT_QRW_25.csv and CT_QRW_25.csv is :
    100%Q  mean(ms)  P50(ms)  P99(ms)  p99.9(ms)  #Samples
0    NaN       0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0       0.0
1    NaN       0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0       0.0
2    NaN       0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0       0.0
3    NaN       0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0       0.0
4    NaN       0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0       0.0
Dataframe for Expected List for file : CT_W_14.csv is 
    100%Q  mean(ms)  P50(ms)  P99(ms)  p99.9(ms)   #Samples
0    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
1    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
2    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
3    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
4    NaN   97.8025  17.8492  725.619    891.455  5304765.0
Dataframe for Actual List for file: CT_W_14.csv is 
    100%Q  mean(ms)  P50(ms)  P99(ms)  p99.9(ms)   #Samples
0    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
1    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
2    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
3    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
4    NaN   97.8025  17.8492  725.619    891.455  5304765.0
Deviation between file CT_W_14.csv and CT_W_14.csv is :
    100%Q  mean(ms)  P50(ms)  P99(ms)  p99.9(ms)  #Samples
0    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN
1    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN
2    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN
3    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN
4    NaN       0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0       0.0
```

Goal:
Since the statements that I have at the moment are print statements hence I will not be able to make it dynamic if I want to convert this into HTML. My goal is to output this as it into an HTML file. Or even if there is a a custom way to add a row as title in the data-frames then that will do. And further on If the deviation is greater than 10% then I want display the cell in red colour. It would be great if anyone has faced such scenario then please help me out. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas have a special object for [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) that can be exported to HTML using its `.render` method or excel with `.to_excel`. You can use CSS to format your table and add captions as such:

```
def highlight_high(series, threshold, colour):
    return ['background-color:'+ colour.lower() if threshold <= i else 'background-color: white' for i in series]

# df.style.apply creates a pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object from a DataFrame
highlighted = df.style.apply(highlight_high, axis=0, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:,'P50(ms)'], colour = 'red', threshold = 0.5)
# adding a caption
highlighted = highlighted.set_caption('Highlighted P50')
# render() generates the HTML for the Styler object
with open('table.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(highlighted.render())
```

I wasn't sure what to colour, so I picked your `Dataframe for Actual List`. `Styler.apply` is for Series-/DataFrame-wise styling and `Styler.applymap` for element-wise. The shapes of input and output of your styling function must match.

- choose slice with `subset` using`pd.IndexSlice`
- set threshold with `threshold`
- choose HTML colour with `colour`
- add a caption with `.set_caption`
- export to HTML `.render` or `.to_excel`

My result:

[image: highlighted_P50]